# API Gateway use variable in apigClient

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to make a function to call my APIs rather than hard code each API call as a separate function. but the usual way of including a variable as the method name is not working. My code is

```
var apiName = 'test';
apigClient[apiName](params, body, additionalParams) etc...
```

Which if I'm right should run as apigClient.test? but it's returning the error of 'apigClient[apiName]' is not a function.  I've also tried apigClient.[apiName] but that throws an error about the unexpected square brackets.

I've tested it by doing,

```
var x = 'log';
console[x]('message');
```

and that works fine??

Comment: Do you want it to run as `apigClienttest` or `apigClient.test`

Comment: apigClient.test 

Comment: Provide your `apigClient`.

Comment: How is apigClient implemented? Is it a JS object/class? It would be helpful if you could provide an example

Comment: It downloads as part of the API Gateway SDK I will have a rummage through the files and try and find it

Comment: @MattM do you create you client instance like this: var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(); ?

Comment: yeah here is my function :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function apiCall(apiUrl, apiName, token) {
    var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
        invokeUrl: apiUrl,
    });

    var params = {
        // This is where any modeled request parameters should be added. The key is the parameter name, as it is defined in the API in API Gateway.
        //param0: ''
    };

    var additionalParams = {
        // If there are any unmodeled query parameters or headers that must sent with the request, add them here.
        headers: {
            'x-cog-token': token,
        },
        queryParams: {
            //param0: ''
        }
    };
    var body = {};
    var apiNewName = 'test';
    var apigClientName = eval("apigClient." [apiNewName]);

    apigClientName(params, body, additionalParams)
        .then(function(result) {
            //API Call Success
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        }).catch(function(result) {
            // API Call Failed

        })
```

Comment: apigClient.test(params, body, additionalParams)... works for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is now working, not sure what to difference is to my first post?

```
    apigClient[apiName](params, body, additionalParams)
        .then(function(result) {
            //API Call Success
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        }).catch(function(result) {
            // API Call Failed

        });
```